# Sharing a list between subsites

Tags: sharepoint-online, list-view, sub-site

I have a view in a SharePoint list in SharePoint 365 that someone in another department wants to display on their SharePoint site.

Both sites are part of the same top-level SharePoint site.

We are on the online version of SharePoint and I cannot find the Content Query web part anymore. I managed to export the web part, but when I uploaded it to the other site, I got an error.

How do I make this list appear on the other subsite?

Comment: Do you need the view or you need to use a column of a list in a lookup column? Becasue in second case you have a solution bases on sites columns

Comment: Do you want to share the data? or do you want to make a list with the sam structure on another site?

Comment: I want to display a view of the list in a different site (same site collection though) with the data. Not a lookup and not an empty list with the same structure. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you are editing your page and you select `Web Part` from the `Insert` Ribbon then you should find the `Content Query` part in the `Content Rollup` category.

If you cannot find that query then you you make sure these site features are enabled:

- SharePoint Server Standard Site features

and these Site Collection Features:

- SharePoint Server Standard Site Collection features
- SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure

If you still cannot see the Web Part, please let me know.

More: If you are using CQWP then you will have to select a layout template for your items.  There are item layout templates for various content types in the Master Page gallery.  If you need a custom layout, you can create one with html and xslt.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery/JavaScript to display your list on another site that is within the site collection. Here is an [article](https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2009/01/22/a-simple-method-to-display-a-list-in-another-site/) that has details go through about this topic. You don't have to use SharePoint Designer (SPD) for this solution.
Here are the main steps of this Process:

1. Activate Publishing Features
2. Create a List
3. Use the Data View Web Part to Display the List
4. Modify the Web Part to Display Your Desired List

And if you are okay with using SPD to do the task, you can follow this [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jackiebo/2007/02/27/displaying-a-list-on-another-site-in-the-same-site-collection/). This is comparatively easy.

As you are saying your content query part is missing. Here is a [solution](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/my-content-query-web-part-is-missing/), about what to do if Content Query Web Part is missing.

Hope this will help.